# Cylindrical capacitor with 2 dielectrics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, capacitance, classical-electrodynamics

**I want to calculate $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{H}$ inside this capacitor**:

[image]

So this would be a cylindrical capacitor but with two different dielectrics in it (they both occupy the same amount of space, excuse me if the drawing I made is not symmetrical). The dielectrics are **not** ideal, so there is current going through them. We could state then that each material has a $\epsilon$ and a $\sigma$. Let's say that these quantities are $\sigma_1$, $\epsilon_1$, $\sigma_2$ and $\epsilon_2$.

The potential difference in the plates is $V_o$ so the electric field will be the same in each material.

$$E = E_1 = E_2 = \frac{V_o}{d}$$

However, different current densities will flow in each material. They can be easily calculated using Ohm's law.

The problem arises when I try to find the magnetic field $\vec{H}$. There is no symmetry in this problem, so I can't use Ampére and take a circulation around the center of the capacitor because $H$ will not be constant for a given radius around the central axis. Also, the fact that different currents are flowing in each material also confuses me. I don't know how to calculate $H$ for a system like this.

Is there a way to find $\vec{H}$ inside this capacitor? Or maybe some software in which I could simulate this?

Comment: Just handwaving here, happy if it actually helps you. Did you try using $\nabla \times H$ = $J_f + \frac{\partial D}{\partial t}$? since you know $D$ and the free current density $J_f$ is the current density produced due to the voltage source alone(exclude magnetization). This immediately tells you that since the currents are longitudinal, the magnetic field $has$ to be circumferential.

Comment: @PrasadMani Hi there, I know that it has to be circumferential but I wanted to know its value (as a function of the conductivities, the permittivities and $V_o$) , not only its direction.

Comment: Which is why you have to calculate the RHS of the above maxwell's equation; again, handwaving, sorry!

Comment: **What is your question?** Why do you need magnetic fields here? Where (inside or  outside the capacitor) would you like to know the magnetic fields, if any?

Comment: @freecharly It is an exercise our teacher gave us, and he told us to calculate $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{H}$ inside the capacitor.

Comment: How is this a capacitor? If currents are running through it, then it is a resistor. Doesn't change the problem though.

Comment: @RobJeffries It can be modelled as two non-ideal capacitors (i.e. with losses) in parallel.

Comment: And what happens about the current flow in the circular plates? This means that the H-field is not just in the azimuthal direction. I don't think that is tractable other than as a numerical/computational problem.

Comment: @RobJeffries Well, that's my question. If you can correctly justify that the H-field is not only azimuthal and there is no analytical solution, then post it in an answer and I may accept it as the correct one.

Comment: When you say current flows through, are you saying that there exists a bound current, a free current, or possibly both? If there is only a bound current (and no free current) then I do believe there is an analytic solution. The azimuthal symmetry would then come from the fact that the permeabilities of the two materials are unspecified (so I assume that they are both $\mu_0$).

Comment: @DillonBerger Sorry for my ignorance, but what is a "bound current"? I've never heard of it (English is not my mother language so maybe I know the concept but in Spanish)

Comment: It's quite alright. If you haven't heard of it yet, you're most likely not supposed to use it. What level class is this for?

Comment: @DillonBerger I just googled it. Yes, I know the term as "magnetization currents". But this is not the case, the currents here are free currents because they come from the expression $J=\sigma E$.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think the electric field, E, is the same in both materials, rather the displacement, D, is--which is the whole point of "D"--it accounts for induced charge at the surface that is caused by divergence of the materials' polarization.

I would treat this problem as 2 uniform capacitors in parallel.

Comment: There is absolute no reference to magnetic field in your answer. Apart from that, you are wrong respecting E and D: E is the same and D differs.